Dice game: Probability of sum of rolls hitting a specific values
The game:
A simple 6-sided fair dice is rolled.
The target is to hit a specific value. You sum the rolls. You may roll the dice as many times as needed until you either reach the specific value (win) or get above it (lost).
If the value to reach is N, what is the probability of winning (i.e. reach the value) as a function of N.
My attempt:
N = 1 : Obviously that's 1/6
N = 2 : A bit more difficult. I could start with rolling 2. Or I could roll 1 and then 1 again.
Like 1/6 + 1/6 * 1/6 = 7/36
N = 3 : oh....
Roll 3 -> 1/6
Roll 2 followed by 1 -> 1/6 * 1/6 = 1/36
Roll 1 followed by 2 -> 1/6 * 1/6 = 1/36
Roll 1 followed by 1 followed by 1 -> 1/6 * 1/6 * 1/6 = 1/216
And then add 1/6 + 1/36 + 1/36 + 1/216 = 49/216
N = 4 : .... I give up ....
Is here a formula/function F(n) that can calculate the probability to reach N.
EDIT
It seems my question isn't clear. So let my try to explain differently.
You get a number N.
Your task is to roll a dice (6 side, fair) to reach zero.
Example 1:
N = 10.
You rool 6. So you are at 10 - 6 = 4
you roll 5. So you are at 4 - 5 = -1. So you lost
Example 2:
N = 10.
You rool 6. So you are at 10 - 6 = 4
You roll 3. So you are at 4 - 3 = 1.
You roll 1. So you are at 1 - 1 = 0. So you won.
What is the probability to win as a function of N

A "field" is just a particular value?  That's not a standard term.

If that's all you meant, then the probability of failing $N$ times in a row is $\left( \frac 56\right)^N$ so the probability of success in $N$ or fewer terms is $1$ minus that.

"Value" is fine.  Or, since the choice of specific value doesn't matter, why not just say "$6$" ?

But it's just not clear...what does "passes it" mean?

Oh, so the value might be much higher than you can reach with one toss of one die?  Are you adding the rolls as you get them?

I feel like I am just guessing at the rules, I suggest trying to clarify your question.

If the goal is to get the exact value $N$ without regard for the number of turns, then you'll want to work recursively.  For instance, you could land on $N-1$ and then get a $1$, and so on.    Note that the last play before you succeed has to be one of $6$ moves, hence a simple recursion.

For large $N$, note that, on average, you roll a $3.5$ each turn so the probability of hitting any particular large $N$ has to be $\frac 1{3.5}=0.285714286$  Your recursion ought to confirm that you approach this value fairly quickly.

@lulu I hope my question is more clear after my edit

If you start at $0$ and have a target of $n$ summing fair dice throws,  then the probability of hitting $n$ rather than passing it is $f(n)$ where $f(n)=(f(n-1)+f(n-2)+f(n-3)+f(n-4)+f(n-5)+f(n-6))/6$ starting from $f(0)=1$ and $f(n)=0$ for $n<0$. Initially you have $f(1)=\frac16$, $f(2)=\frac7{36}$, $f(3)=\frac{49}{216}$, $f(4)=\frac{343}{1296}$, $f(5)=\frac{2401}{7776}$, $f(6)=\frac{16807}{46656}$, $f(7)=\frac{70993}{279936}$.  You will find that for $n\ge 14$ you have $0.28 \lt f(n) \lt 0.29$ and for $n\ge 34$ you have $0.28571 \lt f(n) \lt 0.28572$ so about $\frac{6}{1+2+3+4+5+6}$.

... and you would get the same results starting at $n$ and having a target of $0$ subtracting fair dice throws with $f(n)$ being the probability of hitting $0$ rather than passing it

@Henry Thanks. Very good explanation.

In retrospect, most of the analysis in this response was anticipated by the comment of Henry, following the answer of 4386427.

Alternative approach:
$\underline{\text{Introduction}}$
My approach will be to provide an algorithm that may routinely be converted into a computer program, so that given any number $~N,~$ you can compute the probability that summing the rolls of a D6 die eventually lands exactly on $~N.~$

$~\underline{\text{Variables} ~E(n) ~\text{and} ~p(n)}$
Let $~E(n)~$ denote the event that summing the rolls of a D6 die eventually lands exactly on $~n.~$
Let $~p(n)~$ denote the probability that event $~E(n)~$ occurred.
The explicit computations of $~p(1), ~p(2), ~\cdots, ~p(6)~$ will be done at the end of this answer.
The algorithm will provide a method of expressing $~p(n)~$ in terms of $~p(n-1), ~p(n-2), ~\cdots, ~p(n-6).~$
With this algorithm, you can express $~p(7)~$ in terms of $~p(6), ~p(5), ~\cdots, ~p(1).~$
Then, you can express $~p(8)~$ in terms of $~p(7), ~p(6), ~\cdots, ~p(2),~$ and so forth.
So, to compute $~p(N),~$ you first have to use the algorithm in a recursive manner, to compute each of $~p(N-1), ~p(N-2), ~\cdots, ~p(N - 6).~$
The difficulty here is that in general, the events $~E(n-1), ~E(n-2), ~\cdots, ~E(n-6)~$ are not mutually exclusive events.

$~\underline{\text{Variables} ~F(n,k) ~\text{and} ~q(n,k)}$
Let $~F(n,1)~$ denote that the event $~E(n-1)~$ occurred.
For $~k \in \{2,3,4,5,6\},~$ let $~F(n,k)~$ denote that event $~E(n-k)~$ occurred, but that none of events $~E(n-1), ~E(n-2), ~\cdots, ~E(n + 1 - k)~$ occurred.
Then, events $~F(n,1), ~F(n,2), ~\cdots, ~F(n,6)~$ are mutually exclusive events.
For $~k \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\},~$ let $~q(n,k)~$ denote the probability that event $~F(n,k)~$ occurred.
Then, $~q(n,k) = p(n-k) \times \dfrac{7-k}{6}.~$ 
That is, the very next die roll, following the occurrence of event $~E(n-k)~$ must be $~\geq k.$
Also, $~[ ~p(n) ~| ~F(n,k) ~] = \dfrac{1}{7-k}.~$

That is, assuming that event $~F(n,k)~$ occurred, of the $~(7 - k)~$ die rolls that immediately followed landing specifically on $~(n-k),~$ exactly one of those die rolls then lands on $~n.~$
Further, the only way that event $~E(n)~$ can occur is if one of the mutually exclusive events $~F(n,1), ~F(n,2), ~\cdots, ~F(n,6)~$ first occurred.
Therefore,
$$p(n) = \sum_{k=1}^6 \{ ~q(n,k) \times [ ~p(n) ~| ~F(n,k) ~]$$
$$= \sum_{k=1}^6 \left\{ ~p(n-k) \times \frac{7-k}{6} \times \frac{1}{7-k} ~\right\}$$
$$ = \frac{1}{6} \sum_{k=1}^6 p(n - k). \tag1 $$
Therefore, (1) above provides the necessary algorithm, so the entire problem reduces to explicitly computing $~p(n) ~: ~n \in \{1,2,\cdots,6\}.$



$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~~p(n) ~: ~n \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}}$
Claim:
For $~n \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\},~$
$$p(n) = \frac{7^{n-1}}{6^n}.$$
Proof of Claim, By Induction:
Clearly,
$$p(1) = \frac{1}{6} = \frac{7^0}{6^1}.$$
$E(2)~$ is represented by the sequences 1-1 and 2, which have collective probability of
$$p(2) = \frac{1}{6^2} + \frac{1}{6} = \frac{7}{6^2}.$$
Therefore, the claim is true for $~n = 1~$ and $~n = 2.$

For any $~n \in \{2,3,4,5\},~$ assume that the claim is true for each $~m \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}~$ such that $~m \leq n.~$
For the event $~E(n+1)~$ to occur, one of the following mutually exclusive (combination of events) must occur.
The first roll is specifically $~(n+1),~$ which has a probability of $~\dfrac{1}{6}~$ of occurring.
Otherwise, the first roll must be some element $~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,n ~\}.$  Each of these rolls has a $~\dfrac{1}{6}~$ probability of occurring.
Assuming that the first roll is $~k \leq n,~$ then, from that point forward, event $~E(n+1-k)~$ must occur.  By inductive assumption, the probability of this happening is $~\dfrac{7^{n-k}}{6^{n+1-k}}.$
Therefore,
$$p(n+1) = \frac{1}{6}$$
$$+ \frac{1}{6} \times \{ ~p(n) + p(n-1) + \cdots + p(1) ~\}$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}$$
$$+ \frac{1}{6} \times \left\{ ~\frac{7^{n-1}}{6^n} + \frac{7^{n-2}}{6^{n-1}} + \cdots + \frac{7^0}{6^1} \right\}.$$
Setting $~x = \dfrac{7}{6},~$ then $~p(n+1)~$ can be re-expressed as
$$p(n+1) = \frac{1}{6} + \left\{ ~\frac{1}{6^2} \times \left[ ~1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{n-1} ~\right] ~\right\}.$$
Note that
$$( ~1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{n-1} ~) \times ( ~x - 1 ~) = x^n - 1.$$
Therefore, with $~x = \dfrac{7}{6},~$ you have that
$$p(n+1) = \frac{1}{6} + \left\{ ~\frac{1}{6^2} \times \left[ ~\frac{x^n - 1}{x - 1} ~\right] ~\right\}$$
$$= \frac{1}{6} + \left\{ ~\frac{1}{6^2} \times \left[ ~\frac{(7/6)^n - 1}{(7/6) - 1} ~\right] ~\right\}$$
$$= \frac{1}{6} + \left\{ ~\frac{1}{6} \times \left[ \frac{7^n}{6^n} - 1 ~\right] ~\right\}$$
$$= \frac{1}{6} \times \left[ ~1 + \frac{7^n}{6^n} - 1 ~\right] $$
$$= \frac{7^{n}}{6^{n+1}}.$$
So, the claim is proven by induction.

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iverson}[1]{\left[\left[\,{#1}\,\right]\right]}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
Lests $\ds{\on{P}_{n}\pars{N}}$ the probability of winning ( arriving to the $\ds{N}$ value with the "sum" of $\ds{n}$ $\mbox{rolls )}$. It is given by
$\ds{\pars{~\iverson{\cdots}\ \mbox{is the}\ Iverson\ Bracket~}}$
\begin{align}
\color{#44f}{\on{P}_{n}\pars{N}} & \equiv
\color{#44f}{\sum_{r_{1}\ =\ 1}^{6}{1 \over 6}\cdots
\sum_{r_{n}\ =\ 1}^{6}{1 \over 6}
\iverson{z^{N}}z^{r_{1}\ +\ \cdots\ +\ r_{n}}}
\end{align}
$\ds{\iverson{z^{N}}z^{r_{1}\ +\ \cdots\ +\ r_{n}}\,\,\,\,}$ is, indeed, equal to $\ds{Kronecker\ Delta\ \delta_{N,\ r_{1}\ +\ \cdots\ +\ r_{n}}\,\,\,\,}$ which enforces the condition $\ds{N = r_{1}\ +\ \cdots\ +\ r_{n}}$.
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\color{#44f}{\on{P}_{n}\pars{N}} & =
\iverson{z^{N}}\pars{{1 \over 6}
\sum_{r\ =\ 1}^{6}z^{r}}^{n} =
{1 \over 6^{n}}\iverson{z^{N}}
\pars{z\,{z^{6} - 1 \over z - 1}}^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 6^{n}}\iverson{z^{N - n}}\pars{1 - z^{6}}^{n}\
\pars{1 - z}^{-n}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 6^{n}}\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}
\iverson{z^{N - n}}\pars{-z^{6}}^{k}\,\pars{1 - z}^{-n}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 6^{n}}\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{k}
\iverson{z^{N - n - 6k}\,\,}\pars{1 - z}^{-n}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 6^{n}}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\iverson{N - n - 6k \geq 0}\times
\\ & \phantom{{1 \over 6^{n}}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}}\pars{-1}^{k}
{-n \choose N - n - 6k}
\pars{-1}^{N - n - 6k}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 6^{n}}\sum_{k = 0}
^{\left\lfloor\pars{N - n}/6\right\rfloor}
\pars{-1}^{k}{N - 6k - 1 \choose N - n - 6k}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\color{#44f}{{1 \over 6^{n}}\sum_{k = 0}
^{\left\lfloor\pars{N - n}/6\right\rfloor}
\pars{-1}^{k}{N - 1 - 6k \choose n - 1}}}
\end{align}
I used this result, to generate a few values, by adding over the allowed values of $\ds{n}$ for a given $\ds{N}$:

